# Getting data from Multiple Combo Box

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm trying to create a program wherein the users will provide their birthdate from multiple combo boxes. One for month, then date, and third is for year. And combine their values into one string. So far, here's my code:

```
        string bdate = " "+  bday_month.SelectedText + " " + bday_date.SelectedText + ", " + bday_year.SelectedText;
        MessageBox.Show(bdate);
```

The problem with this is that when I have values for all combo boxes, bdate only displays the third combo box value. See below:

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ComboBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property instead of the [`ComboBox.SelectedText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string bdate = " " +  bday_month.Text + " " + bday_date.Text + ", " + bday_year.Text;
MessageBox.Show(bdate);
```

The `ComboBox.SelectedText` property returns the text highlighted in the editor, but not the entire text.

Comment: Thank you Sir! Didn't notice there was .Text property there. My bad.

Comment: yes sir, still have minutes left to mark your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
comboBox.SelectedText
```

is a value indicating the currently selected text in the control and

```
comboBox.Text
```

is the current text in the `ComboBox`

so use `.Text` instead